# ASP.NET Web API - How to Create Different Action Methods for Routes "product/id" and "product?someOtherId=10"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

With Web API, I need to redirect the following two Restful routes to two different action methods:

**/products/2** -> Get info for product id 2

**/products?someOptionalId=456** -> Get info for all products. Use someOptionalId as a filter if provided.

Unfortunately using the standard routing and model binding scheme, since both URLs point to the same **products controller** and have **one id as a parameter**, I either run into a compile time issue creating two Get methods with same int parameter, or a run time issue with MVC not able to pick a particular action method

**Compile time error**

```
public IQueryable<Product> Get(int someOptionalIdQs)
{

}

public Product Get(int id)
{

}
```

**Run time error (Note hack to use a string for someOptionalIdQs and then convert to int)**

```
public IQueryable<Product> Get(string someOptionalIdQs)
{

}

public Product Get(int id)
{

}
```

Please suggest a fix ideally without having to make any routing config changes given that I would like to keep the routing as clean as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your Method has an optional Id parameter you can simply use a nullable int for the Get for the collection.

The code below will support the following urls:

- http:// server /api/products
- http:// server /api/products?someOptionalIdQs=3
- http:// server /api/products/2

**Code example**

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    public IQueryable<Product> Get([FromUri] int? someOptionalIdQs = null)
    {
        if(someOptionalIdQs.HasValue)
        {
            //apply the filter
        }
        return new List<Product>().AsQueryable();
    }

    public Product Get(int id)
    {
        return new Product();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your first approach but try renaming one of your Get methods.  Note that if the action name doesn't have a prefix of 'Get', make sure the [HttpGet] attribute is used.

```
    // [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Product> Get2(int someOptionalIdQs)
    {
    }

    public Product Get(int id)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do it probly see if the `this.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("someOptionalIdQs")` then do the processing according to Option Id Qs else your normal work flow would work.

But this would be a cryptic implementation an ideally you should create a new URL all together for a different work flow for the app.